# How to add an 'image' property to questions in SurveyJS Creator?

Tags: surveyjs

In our application, the surveys that we create need to support an 'easy read' format whereby an image may be attached to any question, to be displayed alongside the question text.

I can't see a way to do this directly via the SurveyJS API properties, i.e. there doesn't seem to be any standard `questionImage` property.  It therefore looks like this would need to be implemented as a custom property.

On that basis, I need to add a custom property to all question types, which the user can populate with an image in the same way as the 'image picker' question type allows you to select images.  Specifically, the use-case we want to support is to open a file browser to the user's local machine and for the selected image to be encoded as a `data:` URI and stored in this property.  (Supporting additional image-entry methods might be useful, but is not required.)

We are in a position to control the rendering of this property for respondents, so I am not concerned about how to make use of this property, just how to get it into the editor UI.  Also, whilst it would be nice to see the image in the editing interface, this is also not essential behaviour at this stage.

From a Google search, I have seen similar questions, where the answer has been to insert an `Image` or `HTML` element into the survey just before the relevant question, however this is not an appropriate solution for our use-case.  Firstly, it makes the survey hard to manage (both fiddly to use and also easy to break things when moving/deleting questions).  Secondly, it means that the Image is rendered before the question, whereas we need it to be rendered as part of the question element (i.e. after the question number, before the question text).

Can anyone give an example for how I can add a new question property that behaves in the manner described above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this property to surveyjs metadata:

```
Survey
    .Serializer
    .addProperty("question", {
        name: "image:file",
        category: "general"
    });
```

Here is the working sample - https://plnkr.co/edit/5wpQMdMq1vxKhWaG